# Web Scraping Innerhtml

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ethereum, innerhtml

I am trying to WebScrape with the BeautifulSoup Python3 library at https://etherscan.io/ for an open-source project. Specifically, I want to grab a row's *txn* address that has a "To" column of "Contract Creation" (i.e., the inner html).

Take for example the line at [this link](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=8086187) using the inspect element feature of firefox:

```
<a href="/address/0x65a0cdb8e79ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234" title="0x65a0cdb8e79ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234">Contract Creation</a>
```

Here is some code:

```
    url = https://etherscan.io/txs?block=8086187
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    page = content.findAll('td', attrs={"span": ""})
    page = ''.join(str(page))
    if(page.find("Contract Creation") != -1):
    ## find tx that matches with contract
    for i in range(len(page)):
            if i+1 != len(page):
            if({LINE AT CURRENT PAGE == "Contract Creation"})
                tx.append(TXN address); break;
```

For this page, expected output should be:

```
0x48a97150373ca517723db6c39eebcda34719e73a9adb975d5912f21c5a9b4971
```

I am having trouble pulling out the specific information. As of now, I am just making sure the page has a contract creation and then trying to find that. I could hardcode it and check for a line that says

```
if(page[i[ == "c" and page[i+1] == "o" and page[i+2] == "n"...)
  txn.append(page(i-someNumber:page[i-anotherNumber])
```

but this isn't efficient.

Even better, would be just getting the contract addresses, which is located in the title. If I can grab the specific `<a href>` line, then I could feasibly grab the contract address: `0x65A0cDb8e79Ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234`

Comment: What data are you trying to get? What about using an api that can do this instead of web scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1. you can use `nth-of-type` and `:contains` to search the 6th column for that string. Then use `:has` to get the parent row and again `nth-of-type` to get the first column value associated with row i.e. the `txn`. The url has query string params so you can pull back more results at a time. You can use `Session` for efficiency of re-using connection.

The idea is to show the components and a framework for matching and extracting. You could be looping a list of urls instead for example.

---

**CSS selectors:**

Diagram explaining selector combination:

<sub>***click to enlarge***</sub>

[image]

---

**Python3:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

results = [] 

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,10):
        r = s.get('https://etherscan.io/txs?ps=51&p={}'.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        txns_current = [item.text for item in soup.select('tr:has(td:nth-of-type(6):contains("Contract Creation")) td:nth-of-type(1)')]
        if txns_current:
            results.append(txns_current)

final = [item for i in results for item in i]
```

---

**Additional reading:**

Css selectors are covered extensively here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors.

Note: support for `:contains` and `:has` is with bs4 4.7.1. `nth-of-type` is widely supported.

You can practice selectors here:

- https://flukeout.github.io/
- https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: Something did not work with this code, but you gave a very detailed explanation (and I believe informed Andrej's answer). Best answer for sure!

Comment: Pleasure. Were you using bs4 4.7.1 and running as above?

Comment: Hrmmm.. I thought I was. Indeed, now it seems to work, so perhaps it was a copy-and-paste error on my part. Glad i chose you as top answer, I suppose! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to print the add

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://etherscan.io/txs?block=8086187'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

data = []
for tr in soup.select('#ContentPlaceHolder1_mainrow tr'):
    if tr.select('td'):
        data.append([td for td in tr.select('td')])

for row in data:
    if row[5].text.strip() == 'Contract Creation':
        address = row[5].select_one('a[title]')['title']
        print('txt address={}'.format(address))
```

This prints:

```
txt address=0x65a0cdb8e79ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234
```

EDIT: You can select the whole row that contains TD with string `Contract Creation` with this CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select('tr:has(td:contains("Contract Creation"))'))
```

This prints:

```
[<tr><td><span class="hash-tag text-truncate"><a href="/tx/0x48a97150373ca517723db6c39eebcda34719e73a9adb975d5912f21c5a9b4971">0x48a97150373ca517723db6c39eebcda34719e73a9adb975d5912f21c5a9b4971</a></span></td><td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><a href="/block/8086187">8086187</a></td><td><span title="Jul-04-2019 05:28:46 PM">1 hr 19 mins ago</span></td><td><span class="hash-tag text-truncate"><a href="/address/0x0031e147a79c45f24319dc02ca860cb6142fcba1">0x0031e147a79c45f24319dc02ca860cb6142fcba1</a></span></td><td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-success rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right btn-icon__inner"></i></span></td><td><i class="far fa-newspaper text-secondary"></i> <a href="/address/0x65a0cdb8e79ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234" title="0x65a0cdb8e79ae3e0c54436362206fd0769335234">Contract Creation</a></td><td>0 Ether</td><td><span class="small text-secondary">0<b>.</b>00104386</span></td></tr>]
```

Comment: I ended up using your code -- thank you, it is quite succint!